# How to calculate AVG into left join between 2 tables?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, google-bigquery, left-join, average

I have to calculate the avg of gross revenue on bigquery (the key is item_id).

```sql
SELECT
  t0.order_create_date AS day,
  t0.site_country AS country,
  p0.product_brand AS brand,
  p0.product_gender AS gender,
  p0.product_department AS department,
  t0.item_qty AS items_sold,
  t0.item_sale_price AS gross_revenue,
  t0.item_net_price AS net_revenue,
FROM
  `transactions` t0
LEFT JOIN
  `products` p0
ON
  t0.item_id = p0.item_id
ORDER BY
  country,
  day ASC
```

I tried this :

```sql
SELECT
  t0.order_create_date AS day,
  t0.site_country AS country,
  p0.product_brand AS brand,
  p0.product_gender AS gender,
  p0.product_department AS department,
  t0.item_qty AS items_sold,
  t0.item_sale_price AS gross_revenue,
  AVG(t0.item_sale_price) AS average_value,

  t0.item_net_price AS net_revenue,
FROM
  `transactions` t0
LEFT JOIN
  `products` p0
ON
  t0.item_id = p0.item_id
ORDER BY
  country,
  day ASC
```

Biquery result:

> `SELECT list expression references t0.order_create_date which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [2:3]`

Comment: you're missing **GROUP BY** clause in your query.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: This is a faq. Re (re)search success: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you didn't aggregate or by all the other columns, except the `average_value` one. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#group_by_clause) you can read more about Group By.

From the names of the columns you are creating, I suppose you also want to have other information such as gross and net revenue. You would have to use some aggregate function on them too, otherwise the error would continue.

Something like the following should probably work:

```
SELECT
  t0.order_create_date AS day,
  t0.site_country AS country,
  p0.product_brand AS brand,
  p0.product_gender AS gender,
  p0.product_department AS department,
  sum(t0.item_qty) AS items_sold,
  sum(t0.item_sale_price) AS gross_revenue,
  AVG(t0.item_sale_price) AS average_value,
  sum(t0.item_net_price) AS net_revenue,

FROM
  transactions t0
LEFT JOIN
  products p0
ON
  t0.item_id = p0.item_id

GROUP BY
  day,
  country,
  brand,
  gender,
  department

ORDER BY
  country,
  day ASC
```